# Copy single file with I/O errors

Tags: hard-drive, error, copy-paste, ntfs, hdd

I would like to copy a file from one disk (HDD with filesystem NTFS) to another (SSD with ExFAT, if it matters).
The problem occurs in the middle of the copy process, showing me the following message:
[image: The Finder can't complete the operation because some data in "File.data" can't be read or written. (Error code -36)]

> The Finder can't complete the operation because some data in "File.data" can't be read or written. (Error code -36)

I have tried to use `cp`, `rsync` and `dd` without any luck.

The `rsync` command (with `--ignore-errors` flag) throws me the following error:

```
rsync: read errors mapping "/Volumes/HDD/File.data": Input/output error (5)
rsync: read errors mapping "/Volumes/HDD/File.data": Input/output error (5)
ERROR: File.data failed verification -- update discarded.
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-51/rsync/main.c(996) [sender=2.6.9]
```

`dd` just copied a partial data (the part before the problematic sector, without skipping it).

Any ideas how to copy this damn file?

Comment: Can you attach the disk to a Windows system and check/repair the filesystem from there?

Comment: Sorry, it's not an option, as I have to buy a new PC and install a Windows OS.

Comment: Besides, I can always connect a Windows and connect this disk to, but I'm trying to solve it from Mac/UNIX base system.

Comment: What was the full `dd` command you used? Have you tried using `ddrescue`?

Comment: Completely forgot about `ddrescue`! Will it work with a single file, like `dd` does?

Comment: It works! @user3439894, please create a proper answer so I'll be able to mark it as a best solution. Thanks.

Comment: “as I have to buy a new PC and install a Windows OS” Maybe it's easier to just install a [throwaway VM directly from Microsoft](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/). But yeah, `ddrescue` is way better since probably you have some kind of hardware issues on that drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from `dd` there is also [`ddrescue`](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/) although it's not a native OS X/macOS utility, however it can be installed in a number of ways. Personally I prefer to compile directly from *source code* however Package Managers like [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) can be used, or a [precompiled binary](https://tinyapps.org/blog/mac/200808220700_ddrescue_for_mac_os_x.html) if one is comfortable accepting a precompiled binary from an non-authoritative source.

Note that to compile from source code or use a package manager you need to have Command Line Tools for Xcode installed. You do not need to have the full Xcode installed, just the Command Line Developer Tools which are only a couple hundred megabyte vs many gigabytes.

The Command Line Tools for Xcode install can be started from Terminal with the following command:

```
xcode-select --install
```

To use `ddrescue` read its manual page, `man ddrescue` in Terminal, or online: [GNU ddrescue Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html)